# How do I use a plist in android?

Tags: android, xml, parsing, plist

I need to use a plist from an existing iOS app in my android project. How can I realize that? I've already searched for a solution and found different parsers. But what is that? Are that programs or are they used in code? Would be happy if someone has a tutorial for converting a plist to xml.

Comment: Does this conversion need to happen offline or in your app?  Also, probably listing some of the links you have looked at would be useful.  Most of the ones I have seen are simple starter code that you will have to adapt to your needs but can be run from your Android App dynamically rather than offline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

http://code.google.com/p/xmlwise/

Comment: Thx, but I didn't get it work well. I finally solved it by using a sql database, for the future I use that for every app because it works in iOS and android.